# Best approach to an API update project

Tags: python, django, api, jupyter-notebook, sendinblue

I'm working in a personal project to segment some data from the Sendinblue Api (CRM Service). Basically what I try to achieve is generate a new score attribute to each user base on his emailing behavior. For that proposed, the process I've plan is as follows:

1. Get data from the API
2. Store in database
3. Analysis and segment the data with Python
4. Create and update score attribute in Sendin every 24 hours

The Api has a Rate limiting 400 request per minute, we are talking about 100k registers right now which means I have to spend like 3 hours to get all the initial data (currently I'm using concurrent futures to multiprocessing). After that I'll plan to store and update only the registers who present changes. I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it and which combinations of tools is better for this job.

Right now I have all my script in Jupyter notebooks and I recently finished my first Django project, so I don't know if I need a django app for this one or just simple connect the notebook to a database (PostgreSQL?), and if this last one is possible which library I have to learn to run my script every 24 hours. (i'm a beginner). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need Django except you want a web to view your data. Even so you can write any web application to view your statistic data with any framework/language. So I think the approach is simpler:

1. Create your python project, entry point main function will execute logic to fetch data from API. Once it's done, you can start logic to analyze and statistic then save result in database.
2. If you can query to view your final result by SQL, you don't need to build web application. Otherwise you might want to build a small web application to pull data from database to view statistic in charts or export in any prefer format.
3. Setup a linux cron job to execute python code at #1 and let it run every 24 at paticular time you want. Link: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux

Comment: Thanks, I'm working in windows, can I run cron job in this sytem?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you are on Window, you have to create a shell script (.bat extension ), your bat file will execute your python code by command line "python....", then you can setup window service schedule to execute this shell script.